# How to disable single option of a select in cakephp with form helper?

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I need to disable a single particular option of a `selectbox` with `form helper` in cakephp. I am creating `selectbox` with below way :

```
<?php 
    $options = array(1=>'Option 1',2=>'Option 2',3=>'Option 3')
    echo $this->Form->input('Model.field', array('options' => $options, 'empty' => '--select--')); 
?>
```

So now i need to disable `Option 2` in selectbox like :

```
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2" disabled="disabled">Option2</option>
    <option value="3">Option3</option>
</select>
```

So is there any disable property available in options array to disable single options?

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 4):

As per the reference of [CakePHP](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::select).

Your can add `disabled` attribute like the below:

```
<?php 
    $options = array(1=>'Option 1',2=>'Option 2',3=>'Option 3')
    echo $this->Form->input('Model.field', array('options' => $options, 'disabled' => array(2), 'empty' => '--select--')); 
?>
```

Hope this help for you.